# Importing table values with Cloudformation in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I've created a CloudFormation stack to create a DynamoDB set of tables I need.
For a specific one, I also need to restore its values... how can I achieve that?

I've searched online but have found not a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done through a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). The resource would be a lambda function which would perform the insertion of your data into the newly created table using AWS SDK.